# setEditing:animated: is missing animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I encountered a problem while programming iOS: When I tried to make my custom edit button for my tableView, I just could not have it animated. Below is how I initialized tableview:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{ 
    [super viewWillAppear:animated]; 

    myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain]; 
    myTableView.delegate = self; 
    myTableView.dataSource = self; 

    myTableView.autoresizesSubviews = YES; 

    .......

    self.view = myTableView; 

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:@selector(setEditing:animated:)];     
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton; 
    [addButton release]; 
}
```

However, when I used self.editButtonItem instead of my addButton, the editing mode IS animated. And here's my setEditing:animated: method. I can get my tableview into editing mode and the insert button appeared immediately to the left. I've tried `[myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[myTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];` 
but it doesn't help on iOS 4.3.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{ 

if(self.editing){ 
    [super setEditing:NO animated:YES]; 
    [myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[myTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]; 
    [myTableView reloadData]; 
    self.navigationItem.title = [selectedCellItem valueForKey:@"name"]; 
    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:@selector(setEditing:animated:)];  
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton; 
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain]; 
    [addButton release]; 
} 
else { 
    [super setEditing:YES animated:YES]; 
    [myTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[myTableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic]; 
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Add to Favourites"; 
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(setEditing:animated:)];     
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton; 
    [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone]; 
    [doneButton release]; 
    [myTableView reloadData]; 
} 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the selectors you are assigning are able to send two arguments:

```
@selector(setEditing:animated:)
```

A button action normally just sends either no arguments, or itself as an argument (usually `(id)sender`). So what you are doing is probably being interpreted as sending NO as the second argument (so `animated = NO`).

You should add a new method like so:

```
-(void)toggleEditing
{
    [self setEditing:!self.isEditing animated:YES];
}
```

And set the action on your buttons:

```
@selector(toggleEditing)
```

**EDIT**

OK, here is some more detailed code for you.

For starters, your initial code sample should be in `viewDidLoad` and not `viewWillAppear`. It should look something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{ 
    [super viewDidLoad];

    .... code where you set up the table view...

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:@selector(toggleEditing)];     
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton; 
    [addButton release]; 
}
```

Your `setEditing` method should be something like this:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    if (editing)
    {
        // We are changing to edit mode
        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(toggleEditing)];     
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneButton; 
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone]; 
        [doneButton release];
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Add to Favourites";
    }
    else
    {
        // We are changing out of edit mode
        self.navigationItem.title = [selectedCellItem valueForKey:@"name"]; 
        UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemBookmarks target:self action:@selector(toggleEditing)];  
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton; 
        [self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain]; 
        [addButton release];
        self.navigationItem.title = [selectedCellItem valueForKey:@"name"];
    } 
}
```

Comment: Try removing the reloadRows.. calls, what are they for? They will replace the cells immediately and could therefore be happening before your animation is complete.

Comment: Yes I've removed the lines. Should I modify my     [super setEditing:NO animated:YES]; ?? I just want to make a customized edit button on my navigation bar. Or where can i find some easy to understand code?

Comment: Still couldn't fix the problem. Could you please give me a complete code? Thank you very much!!!